# Facebook Connect compile error

Tags: iphone, fbconnect

Am getting 1 warning and 1 error on compiling my iPhone app with FBConnect in there.  The error is:

```
  literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@FBSession
```

Any thoughts on what the problem is and how to track it down?

Regards

Dave

Comment: It's a linker error, there's information on Google: http://www.google.ca/search?q=literal-pointer

Comment: Thanks Eric, you were right!  Cheers Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like linker error. Make sure that you've added all files from FBConnect to your project (especially FBSession.m file).

Comment: Thanks, yes it was a link error.  I mistakenly thought that because it found the .h files it was a compile error.  Thanks again, Dave